# The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, .net, debugging

I have read a lots of guides over internet, but stuck in this issue.

I have created a `Class Library (.NET Framework)`
project called `JuiceShopAutomation`.

where I have installed following `Nuget` packages:

```
Selenium.WebdDriver (v3.8.0)<br>
Selenium.Support (v3.8.0)<br>
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (v2.33.0)<br>
Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver (v0.19.1)<br>
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver  (v3.8.0)<br>
MSTest.TestFramework (v1.2.0)<br>
MSTest.TestAdapter(v1.2.0)
```

I have also added following code to `Class1.CS`

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace JuiceShopAutomation
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public void Go()
        {
           
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\WebDriver", "geckodriver.exe");   
            service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }
    }
}
```

I also have added another project to my solution, a new `Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)` called `JuiceshopTests`.

For `JuiceShopTests` I add the reference `Project>Juiceshop Automation` where all things are installed.

[image]

To the new Unit test project I add following code into the file `UnitTest1.cs`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using JuiceshopAutomation;

namespace JuiceshopTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var c = new Class1();

            c.Go();

        }
    }
}
```

Then when I run the `unit test` it fails and throws the below `error`:

```
Test Name:  TestMethod1
Test FullName:  JuiceShopTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
Test Source:    C:\Users\XXXXXX\source\repos\Creating an Automated Framework With Selenium\JuiceShopAutomation\JuiceShopTests\UnitTest1.cs : line 12
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:01:01,3130361

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service)
   at JuiceShopAutomation.Class1.Go() in C:\Users\XXXXXX\source\repos\Creating an Automated Framework With Selenium\JuiceShopAutomation\JuiceShopAutomation\Class1.cs:line 20
   at JuiceShopTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\Users\XXXXXX\source\repos\Creating an Automated Framework With Selenium\JuiceShopAutomation\JuiceShopTests\UnitTest1.cs:line 16
Result Message: 
Test method JuiceShopTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:60378/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried just calling the default `CreateDefaultSerivce()` without params? And what is your Firefox browser version?

Comment: I think actually I solved it by change geckodriver to an older version then it seems like it works.

Comment: Great! Consider posting and accepting your own answer for others who may run into the same problem.

Comment: @HaC shall I just post my own answer? then

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to downgrade the geckodriver from 19.01 to 18.00 and also downgrade Mozilla Firefox.

Then it worked as fine!

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be running the selenium server or a selenium grid for it to connect to.

Your create method is failing to start or detect the server, this could be for a number of reasons.

Failure to detect means it's probably not running.
Failure to start means Permissions or Configuration failure are the most likely.